# How to load a string of text relating to a spinner selection

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, spinner

I Have a spinner displaying a list from an array, what I want to do is have the selected option display a more detailed selection in a window below the array.

The reason I am after this is I want to build a character creation tool and I want people to be able to pick from a list of option and then depending on the option they select bring up a description of what that selection means.

So far I have my Array in strings.xml which is:

```
<string-array name="humanBackgroundData">
    <item>Cultist</item>
    <item>Freed Slave</item>
    <item>Gangster</item>
    <item>Techno-Reaper</item>
    <item>Tribal</item>
    <item>Wanderer</item>
    <item>Dwelled in the Dwelling</item>
    <item>Feral Child</item>
    <item>Welsh/Scottish Descendant</item>
</string-array>
```

And my Spinner which is in the activity.xml:

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinB"
    android:entries="@array/humanBackgroundData"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    >
```

I have been searching for a way to link the selected option to another string which could then show additional data for that selection. I want to do this because having a ton of data in the spinner will look terrible. I have seen methods of numbering the spinner so that the first selection would be 1 and the second 2 so I believe I should be able to use that as a reference to invoke a string, but I have only been working with android studio for around two weeks and I cannot find any other posts about doing this. any suggestions?

Thanks for your time :)

*Update*

I have now partialy found a solution, I can now get the TextView to reference the string if I contain it within the activity, however I want to pull it from strings.xml so it keeps things a bit tidier and stops me repeating myself so much. I have linked my code below. If I replace the "textnone" with "text1" it works so I think it is just a problem with the way I have linked the string array.

```
    <string-array name="humanBackgroundData">
    <item>Cultist</item>
    <item>Freed Slave</item>
    <item>Gangster</item>
    <item>Techno-Reaper</item>
    <item>Tribal</item>
    <item>Wanderer</item>
    <item>Dwelled in the Dwelling</item>
    <item>Feral Child</item>
    <item>Welsh/Scottish Descendant</item>
</string-array>


package com.studios.grimvoodoo.spicedcharacterbuilder;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HumanActivity extends Activity {

private static Button proceed;

Resources res = getResources();
String[] text1 = res.getStringArray(R.array.ghulBackgroundData);


String[] textnone = {"human", "ghul", "postgen",
        "gnome", "pixie", "giant", "vampire"};

String[] text2 = {"standard", "undead", "super mutant", "wee man", "flying    wee man", "big and hungry", "dead and loving it"};

Spinner spinner1;
TextView textView1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_human);

    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(HumanActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, text1);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener1);
}

AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener1 =
        new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
                String s1 = String.valueOf(text2[position]);
                textView1.setText(s1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }

        };
}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.studios.grimvoodoo.spicedcharacterbuilder.HumanActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:text="http://android-er.blogspot.com/"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner0"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text0"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>


    <string-array name="humanBackgroundData">
    <item>Cultist</item>
    <item>Freed Slave</item>
    <item>Gangster</item>
    <item>Techno-Reaper</item>
    <item>Tribal</item>
    <item>Wanderer</item>
    <item>Dwelled in the Dwelling</item>
    <item>Feral Child</item>
    <item>Welsh/Scottish Descendant</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right, you should put additional TextView below Spinner in layout. Then create separate string array with additional infos (info array), with same size as your existing string array.

Then in spinner's onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int pos, long id) method, get position of selected spinner element (pos) and update TextView with corresponding element from your infos array (element with index pos).

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tonight :)